# how to remove certain strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, `df` with a column that has different school names, `school_name`. I want to remove certain words, and wonder what the best way to go about this might be.

For example, I want to remove `‘male’` and `‘female’` from strings like:

```
‘gps hafiz shahmale p’
‘gpps mogal malep’ 
‘government primary school chak femalep’ 
‘govt girls high school syebadadfemale p’ 
‘ghs male p’
…
```

There are many other strings besides `‘male’` or `‘female’` that I want to remove that have similar complexities, e.g:

I also want to remove `‘sbcombined’` from strings like:

```
'government girls high school chak no120sbcombinedp',
'govt boys elementary school chak no119sbcombined t',
'govt boys elementary school chak no 37 sbcombined p'
…
```

All I could think of now is to write separate functions for each words, e.g. to remove `‘male’`:

```
l = df.school_name.tolist()

for i in l: 
    if (i[-4:]=='male') or (i[-5:-1]=='male' and i[-7:-5]!='fe'):
        i2 = i.replace('male', '')
    df.loc[df.school_name==i, school_name] = i2
```

Is there a better, more efficient way to go about this?

edit: I also would like to know how I could deal with the complexity involved with the string 'male' - 'male' is part of the string 'female' (which I want to remove as well), that when I use re.search to remove the word 'male', for strings that include the word 'female', the 'male' part of the 'female' word gets removed that only 'fe' is left behind; something which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace)

```
pattern = '|'.join(['male','female'])
df['school_name'] = df.school_name.str.replace(pattern, '')
```

It will replace all words in list with `''` empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If you can specificy words you want to remove in a list `replace_word_list`, try something like:

```
for word in replace_word_list:
    df['school_name'] = df['school_name'].str.replace(word, '')
```